# Scala: Import scala.io.StdIn.readLIne -- error importing

Tags: scala

I am getting an error if I import readline, as follows:

`import scala.io.StdIn.{readline, readInt}` =>

```
error: value readline is not a member of object scala.io.StdIn
import scala.io.StdIn.{readline, readInt}
```

- Scala code runner version 2.12.1

If I don't import this, I get a deprecated message:

```
warning: there was one deprecation warning (since 2.11.0); re-run with -deprecation for details
one warning found
```

I get no errors if I use the fill path to the function:

```
var x = scala.io.StdIn.readLine.toInt
```

Let me know if you can help me resolve the import.  Thanks.

Comment: Yup thanks. New to scala, slight oversight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very tiny overlook:

```
import scala.io.StdIn.{readLine, readInt}
```

`readLine` has an upper case L

Comment: Jinx. The obvious follow-up is why doesn't the compiler tell us that in 2017?

Comment: @som-snytt some do, Scala's doesn't at least for now. I know they're working on better error messages for the new compiler, and would be glad to take contributions.